Does the following sequence of random variables converge in probability and fit the additional requirements?
The exercise is to find a sequence of random variables with the following properties:

$(X_n)$ converges to $0$ in probability.
With probability 1, the sequence has $\limsup_n X_n = \infty$ and $\liminf_n X_n = -\infty$.

My Approach
We define:
$$
X_n = \begin{cases}
+n & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2n}, \\
-n & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{2n}, \\
0 & \text{with probability } 1 - \frac{1}{n}.
\end{cases}
$$
This sequence obviously converges to zero in probability: $P(|X_n|>e)$ is equal to the probability of $X_n$ not being zero. We therefore get $\lim 1/n$ which is zero as $n$ approaches infinity.
For the second part: I tried arguing that using Borel-Cantelli we can observe that with probability $1$ we get the event $X_n=n$. The same follows for $X_n = -n$.
My only concern is that the last step of what is supposed to be a proof feels more like an explanation:
Since we know that $X_n = n$ with probability $1$ the $\limsup_n X_n = \infty$ with probability $1$. This works vice versa for $X_n = -n$ utilizing the general statement $\limsup_n \geq \liminf_n$.
I would appreciate if somebody could help me make this a more rigorous proof!

Let $A_n:=\{X_n=n\}$. We know that the sequence $(A_n)$ is independent and that $\sum_n\mathbb P(A_n)=\infty$. By the second Breol-Cantelli lemma, the event $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$ has probability $1$. As a consequence, there is $\Omega'$ having probability one such that for each $\omega\in\Omega'$, there exists an infinite set $I(\omega)\subset\mathbb N$ such that $\omega\in A_{i}$ for each $i\in I(\omega)$. This means that for $i\in I(\omega)$, $X_i(\omega)=i$. A sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_i=i$ for infinitely many $i$ necessarily satisfies $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$.
The argument for the $\liminf$ is analogous: take $B_n=\{X_n=-n\}$, we get a set $\Omega''$ of probability one such that for each $\omega\in\Omega''$, there exists an infinite set $I'(\omega)\subset\mathbb N$ such that for each $i\in I'(\omega)$, $\omega\in B_i$. We get that for such $i$, $X_i(\omega=-i$.
